# Unable to ping my Ubuntu AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ping, ubuntu-11.10

I'm new to AWS, just setup a ubuntu ec2 and I've made a security group which allows me to ssh in and that's about all for now.  What do I have to do to make it so I can also ping my instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the security group for the instance, click on the "inbound" tab, choose "Create a new rule" dropdown and select "All ICMP" and then click +Add Rule, then click Apply Rule Changes.  The change takes effect immediately.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make sure it allows ICMP packets to be seen/not firewalled.

Comment: +1. Pings are blocked by default by the AWS security groups.

Comment: I edited my security group and added all ICMP packets - Very easy :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just go to the security group, click on the "inbound" tab, choose "Create a new rule" dropdown and select "All ICMP" and then click +Add Rule

Comment: What's the option to select if you don't want all ICMP, just ping?

Comment: ICMP is mostly for diagnostics, like traceroute along with ping. What would you gain by trying to block out everything but just ping? (I'm not sure you could block everything but ping with the tools they have available, although I suppose on the VM you can use the firewall tools to try to refine it...)

Comment: I have ICMP traffic open, but I still can't ping my ubuntu server instance.  I started one of my windows server 2008 instances and I can ping that one fine, so my issue is not with the security group.  it seems to be more ubuntu/instance specific, but I just used the basic amazon ubuntu server 64 bit option and started it, then installed MongoDB.  Any ideas why I still can't ping?  Thanks!